# transposition in R (id)

Tags: r

I found that after transposing, the original column variable now becomes the id in the dataset of R itself. How can I change the id of R. I want the id to be (1,2,3 in numerical order, not the name of my original column variable).

This is my origianl dataset
[image]

When I did the transpose, I got this dataset

[image]

I want the id of my transposed dataset to look like this.

[image]

This is my hard code
con <- read_csv("")

t1 <- t(data.frame(con,row.names=1))

t2 <- as.data.frame(t1,row.names=F)

HBName <- c("Scotland","East Region","NHS Borders","NHS Fife","NHS Lothian","North Region","NHS Highland2")

t3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(HBName,t2))

How do I do this, is there any simple way to do it, even though I have hard coded it to make what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear and you have only provided an for your dataset. So assuming that your original dataframe looks like the one given below,

```
> df
                 Scotland East Region
All specialities 4922.616    1281.781
```

And so you when you take transpose of the above given dataframe then the column names are changed into rownames as given below,

```
> df <- t(df)
> df
                    All specialities
Scotland            4922.616
East Region         1281.781
```

To keep the `speciality` names as a column you can save the rownames as a `speciality` column in the dataframe as given below,

```
> df$speciality <- rownames(df)
> df
                All.specialities  speciality
  Scotland            4922.616    Scotland
  East Region         1281.781 East Region
```

Then in order to change the rownames to 1,2,3 you can assign rownames for the dataframe to NULL,

```
 > rownames(df) <- NULL
 > df
           All.specialities  speciality
 1         4922.616          Scotland
 2         1281.781          East Region
```

Best

Comment: Thank you very much,  I am very sorry that I did not express my words clearly.